# How to check valid object of class in smarty?

Tags: php, smarty

Is there any function in smarty to check valid object of class in smarty?

Suppose `$obj` is having some value or not.

How to check `$obj` is object of 'TestClass' or not in smarty?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the way to check variable is object of specific class in Smarty.

```
if( true eq isset($obj) && true eq is_object($obj) && $obj instanceof 'TestClass' ){
//do something
}
```

Answer (score 6):

this works in Smarty2 and Smarty3:

```
{if $obj instanceof TestClass}
  …
{/if}
```

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
if($obj instanceof TestClass )
{
    echo 'yes';
}
else
{
    echo 'no';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

here is good example for this.

```
{if is_object($obj)}
  {*=== your code ===*}
{else}
  {*=== your code ===*}
{/if}
```

we can use is_object to know that this is an object or not.

hope it will help someone..

Answer (score 1):

you can call php functions in the smarty code. Try this:

```
{if $customer instanceof Customer}
    YES, instance of Customer
{else}
    NO, Not an instance
{/if}
```

Also, it might be good idea to check if the variable is actually set before using it if the controller code has many paths:

```
{if isset($customer) && $customer instanceof Customer}
    YES, instance of Customer
{else}
    NO, Not an instance
{/if}
```

Comment: Do you see any errors when you try it, I can confirm that it works for me when I use it in a template. I am using smarty 3 by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Function [`is_a`](http://php.net/is_a) could be used for this.

```
{if is_a($customer, 'Customer')}
    YES, instance of Customer
{else}
    NO, Not an instance
{/if}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the specific class of the object as well if needed with `$obj|get_class`

Example:

```
{if $animal instanceof Horse}
    <span>Yup, it's a horse class.</span>
{else}
    <span>It is actually a {{$animal|get_class}}</span>
{/if}
```